# How do I upload a file to sharepoint with the office365 dlls

Tags: c#, sharepoint, file-upload, office365

I tried to upload a file to OneDrive for Business/SharePoint using the following dlls:

> Microsoft.Office.Oauth 
>   Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint;
>   Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.Extensions;

With the following code:

```
public async void UploadDataAsync(byte[] bytes, string fileName)
{

    // NAME: TestFolder, ID: TestFolder, URL: /personal/[company]_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TestFolder,                                                 SIZE: 0

    UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation();
    userInformation.Id = "Castrovalva";
    userInformation.Name = "Castrovalva";

    Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.File file = new Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.File();
    file.CreatedBy = userInformation;
    file.LastModifiedBy = userInformation;
    file.Id = fileName;
    file.Name = fileName;
    file.Url = "/personal/[company]_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/TestFolder";
    file.TimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
    file.TimeLastModified = DateTime.Now;
    file.ETag = "ETAG";

    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        await file.UploadAsync(memory);
    }
}
```

I get this error when I try to run this code:

> System.Exception: {"cannot find entity"} 
>   Source: Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint

What I dont understand is that I don't need the SharePointClient (client connected to sharepoint) object to execute the code.
Because when I want to get the information of all my files or have to connect I use this object.

```
_client = await EnsureClientCreated();
_client.Context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
```

So how do I upload a file to OneDrive for Business/SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

I found myself a solution, it was more simple then I would have expected:

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    try
    {
        //await _client.Context.ExecuteAsync(uri, "POST", stream);
        await _client.Files.AddAsync(fileName, true, stream);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
    { MessageBox.Show(exception.Message); }
}
```